# Autolykos GPU Miner software no longer recognizing NVIDIA GPU on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: cuda, nvidia

A month or so ago, Autolykos miner (https://github.com/ergoplatform/Autolykos-GPU-miner) compiled and ran. Now suddenly it doesn't work because the .cu files don't recognize any installed NVIDIA GPU. I made NO changes to the Autolykos code--it just stopped working.  I merely dropped into the source folder (as described by the README) and typed `make`.  But when I install and make all of the CUDA examples, THOSE run just fine. Running on UBUNTU 18.04 with a GeForce TITAN X. For example, the utility "deviceQuery" returns the following:

```
./deviceQuery Starting...

CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "GeForce GTX TITAN X"
CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version 10.1 / 10.1
CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number: 5.2
...
```

Whereas the output at startup of the mining binary spits out ONE line and quits:

`Error Checking GPU:  Using 0 GPU devices`

Any suggestions would be welcome...

Comment: To whomever downgraded my question, would you please tell me what I need to do to make the question better (rather than just downgrading).  Otherwise how else will I learn?

Comment: A few suggestions, in no particular order: 1. Better question formatting.  There are tools available to make that output look better and easier to read.  I think I could do it in about 5 clicks.  2. A reference to how to find/download/install/test Autolykos  3.  A [mcve], which is actually required, see item 1 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  4. most of the text in your answer is for `deviceQuery`, which is working correctly.  It's helpful, but not that useful to solving the problem.  Add the actual session output when you run and get the errror

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SOLVED:  After re-compiling the CUDA code from NVIDIA, the miner is working.  I suspect that a system update broke something